# Can you use lambda expressions in a JPA Entity with good performance?

Tags: java, jpa, lambda

So, I have a OneToMany relationship in one of my entites:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("priority")
    private List<Result> results
```

I want to get objects contained inside of these "results" based on by some criteria:

```
Stream<Item> itemsToReturn = results.stream().filter(result -> result.getPriority() > 5)
                .map(Result::getItem)
                .filter(/*some filtering logic*/)
                .limit(numberOfItems);
```

It doesn't seem to be very effective though, since I guess all Items will be loaded into memory before any filtering is done in spite of the filtering and the limit.

Is my assumption correct? If so, can I do something so that I can use lambda in this entity, or I should write a JPA query to get these items?

Can lambdas be used with JPA at all?

Comment: As @Sleiman indicates, this is very possibly a very expensive operation.  Why would you replace the database that is in part built to do where clauses with a simple linear search?  I'd reject this code if it was up to me to review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether  it is good or not depends on how big your result set is. But it is worth knowing whats gonna happen when you execute your code.

1. A full scan will execute on the db table
2. The entire table data will be traveling over the network wire
3. The entire result set will be loaded into the JVM main memory
4. A linear scan will execute over the entire result when you do the filer over the stream

The above code is not any different from an old fashion for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

JPA entity should be POJO class with plain fields, collections, get/set methods and nothing more. I suggest to move all logic to [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) classes.

Answering to your question: JPA already has filtering (aka [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html)) which works fast enough. There is no need to use lambdas for filtering in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

With [Jinq](http://www.jinq.org/), it is possible to use lambdas for queries and gain good database-performance as well, in Java with JPA.

Jinq is similar to Linq in C#, so the lambda-queries are translated to SQL (JPQL) and executed by the database like any other query - they are not executed by Java. (*)

An quick example slightly similar to yours could look something like this in Jinq:

```
List<Item> items = jinq.users()
    .where(user -> user.getId() == someId)
    .selectAllList(user -> user.getItems())        // <- a very simple type of join
    .where(item -> item.getPriority() > 5)
    .where(item -> /*some more filtering logic*/) 
    .limit(numberOfItems)
    .toList();                                     // <- this fetches the result from the DB
```

---

(*) *Note, that this obviously also means that there are restrictions on what you can put in your lambdas - you can't call arbitrary java methods, for example, as the database-engine can't execute those. Only a limited set of methods are allowed - entity relationship getter-methods are one example of such allowed methods.*